# How to plot "datetime" data versus numbers? "Error: Data inputs must match the axis configuration..."

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, io

I have data in an external .txt file.  There are columns of numbers.  There is also a first column of "datetime" data where is format is:

```
2015-07-01 01:00:00
```

I am a relative newbie to Matlab.  I can import all of the data, but cannot figure out how to plot the datetime data versus a column of numbers.  When I do:

```
  DT_1_formatted = datetime(DT_1, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
  t = datetime(DT_1_formatted);
  plot(t, numbersColumn);
```

I get this error:

```
Data inputs must match the axis configuration. A numeric axis must have numeric data inputs or data inputs which can be converted to double.
```

Another problem is that the output printed to screen shows that the datetime format is wrong.  It's:

```
0-Jul-2019 23:00:00
```

I'm using Matlab 2016a.

Comment: What's `numbersColumn`?

Comment: @Paolo, numbersColumn would be a column of floats, like "1000.0," for example.  It would be the same length as the datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and will post the answer here for other newbies, as I bet there are other people who need to plot timeseries data who will have the same problem.

```
  DT_1_test = datetime(DT_1, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Format', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
  t = datetime(DT_1_test);
  plot(datenum(t), n_raw1);
  datetick('x', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Note that to format the on-screen datetime AND the plotted datetime correctly, I had to use "InputFormat" and "Format" in the first line.  To get a date and not numbers on the X axis, I had to use "datetick," a suggestion I got from another forum.